# How to format time in React SSR rendered page using client time zone?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I'm building a website with React and recently switched to using server-side rendering (SSR) for improved performance. One issue I ran into after this change is that when I format a time on the page (I'm using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)) it renders incorrectly using the server's time zone.

How can I format the time using the client's time zone? Do I need to leave the time off on the server response and have the client render that afterwards?

Answer (score 5):

> Do I need to leave the time off on the server response and have the client render that afterwards?

Unfortunately yes.

You can build a utility component to make this less tedious.

Class component:

```js
// utility
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Class component
export default class ClientRender extends Component {
  state = { isMounted: false };
  
  componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({ isMounted: true });
  }

  render () {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { isMounted } = this.state;
    
    return isMounted ? children : null;
  }
}

// Function component
export default function ClientRender({ children }) {
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);
  }, []);

  return isMounted ? children : null;
}
```

---

```js
// in your app
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

import ClientRender from './path/to/client-render';

export default function MyComponent (props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ClientRender>{moment(props.timeUTC * 1000).format('LLL')}</ClientRender>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why not render server-side with a default timezone in state and set the client timezone to state in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: @coreyward would prefer to never show the user a potentially wrong time.

Comment: @LironYahdav The only case where that would happen is if they have JavaScript disabled, in which case this solution won't work.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough. I meant that I don't want to render server-side with a default timezone because that means that end users will see times formatted in a potentially incorrect timezone for a brief moment. There's no way for that default timezone to be correct for all users. This can happen when JS is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this with React, specifically, but the general approach is to render a `<time>` element ([documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time)) with a full date/time format that contains the timezone, then adjust the text output client-side.

This should be fairly straightforward when you rehydrate client-side; `react-moment` also accepts a [timezone](https://github.com/headzoo/react-moment#timezone) if you're rendering server-side per request…

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

One thing that you may try is to set a cookie client-side with the timezone as value.

The first visit of a client will always be an issue so be prepared to use a default timezone or delay rendering (with didMount event).

But once a client comes back with said cookie you can use that cookie value as the timezone for date and time string rendering.

Not tried it yet, I will try to think about updating that post if I'm successful